# How to programmatically hide the NSTextView's Find Bar?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nstextview

When the user starts a find action in a `NSTextView` control (for example by hitting ⌘ + F on the keyboard), a find bar becomes visible, when property `usesFindBar` is set to true. That's great.

But how do I hide this bar programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @apodidae helpful answer, I was able to get a working solution after adding a `NSTextFinder` object to the view controller in the storyboard, and connecting the `client` outlet of this object to the `NSTextView` control and `findBarContainer` to the scrollview of the said text view.

Then after connecting a newly created `textFinder` outlet variable in the view controller to the text finder object in the storyboard, this code line of @apodidae (translated to Swift) eventually works:

```
textFinder.performAction(.hideFindInterface)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)hideTextFinder{
 [txtFinder performAction:NSTextFinderActionHideFindInterface];
}
```